Unresolved external symbol - pcap functions
I know this question has been asked multiple times and it's probably something simple that I'm missing but i cant seem to figure it out. I've looked at this and this.
I'm trying to compile this github repo arpspoof using visual studio (i've tried both 2019, and 2022. Currently using 2019). I've added the pcap header (i cant seem to upload images for some reason). Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directoires: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\ncap-sdk-1.12\Include
Then added the Linker options. Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories: C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\npcap-sdk-1.13\Lib\x64; and under Properties -> Linker -> General -> Input -> Additional Dependencies: Ws2_32.lib;Iphlpapi.lib;wpcap.lib;Packet.lib.
I've run a dumpbin on the wpcap.lib file to confirm it has the functions exported that visual studio is complaining about.
dumpbin /exports wpcap.lib
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.41.34120.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file wpcap.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  bpf_dump
                  bpf_filter
                  bpf_image
                  bpf_validate
                  eproto_db
                  pcap_activate
                  pcap_breakloop
                  pcap_bufsize
                  pcap_can_set_rfmon
                  pcap_close
....

I've also copied wpcap.lib to another directory (sorry dont remember which and it appears to be on another system).
All of these changes are made under "All Configurations" and "x64" platform.
But i still get a LNK2001 error for pcap functions

pcap_next_ex
pcap_freealldevs
pcap_datalink
pcap_open_live
pcap_geterr
pcap_sendpacket
pcap_findalldevs
pcap_close

Oh also installed the installer and the SDK from npcap.com
Here is the log. What am i missing?
